# Python global/package alias implementation class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have that strange feeling this is an easy question.

I want to be able to "alias" a class type so i can swap out the implementation at a package level.  I dont want to have X amount of `import X as bah` scattered throughout my code...

Aka. How can I do something like the below:

```
class BaseClass(object):
   def __init__(self):  pass
   def mymthod(self): pass
   def mymthod1(self): pass
   def mymthod2(self): pass

class Implementation(BaseClass):
   def __init__(self):
       BaseClass.__init__()
```

Seperate package...

```
#I dont want thse scattered through out modules, 
#i want them in one place where i can change one and change implementations  
#I tried putting it in the package init but no luck
import Implementation as BaseClassProxy


class Client(BaseClassImpl):
    def __init__(self):
       BaseClassImpl.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any file (where this fits best is up to you, probably wherever `Implementation` was defined):

```
BaseClassProxy = Implementation
```

Since classes are first class objects in Python, you can pretty much bind them to any variable and use them the same way. In this case, you can make an alias for the class.

Comment: Works perfectly, but I should note you need to import the "class/alias" from where ever it is defined.    Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

just put something like

```
BaseClassProxy = Implementation
```

in the module, then do:

```
from module import BaseClassProxy
```